# How to disable the left borders of a column's cells in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, border, cell

How can I disable the left borders of a column's cells in a DataGridView? I have done some research. I believe the answer lies within the following resources somewhere, but I haven't found the solution so far:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewadvancedborderstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewadvancedborderstyle.bottom(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.adjustcellborderstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

Any suggestion?

Comment: You are on the right track. It is rather more complicated than one would hope for.. You need to create a DGV subclass, like in the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewadvancedborderstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and modify it..

Comment: Thanks for advice. I'll do my best.